# Double proceed to checkout button in wordpress checkout

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, duplicates, checkout

Wordpress Checkout Page problem. I'm getting this error while checkout. I tried to remove button using CSS but it's remove both of the buttons.

I tried to deactivate & activating all the plugins & also tried updating theme but none of these methods works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this double proceed to checkout button in woocommerce, You can solve it but disabling change cart button text option :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9akl.png)